# Has Many Through w/ Conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm using a has_many through relationship in Rails 4, that looks like this:

```
has_many :collection_memberships, as: :collectable
has_many :collections, through: :collection_memberships
has_many :brands, -> { where(kind: 'brand') }, class_name: Collection,
         through: :collection_memberships, source: :collection
```

If I have an object called `my_obj` and and do `my_obj.brands`, it works as expected:

```
SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" INNER JOIN "collection_memberships"
 ON "collections"."id" = "collection_memberships"."collection_id" WHERE 
 "collections"."kind" = 'brand' AND "collection_memberships"."collectable_id"
 = $1 AND "collection_memberships"."collectable_type" = $2  ORDER BY
 collection_memberships.position ASC
```

But, if I try to use `:includes` to do some eager loading:

`p = Product.where(id: product_ids).includes(:brands)`

This happens:

```
Product Load  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."id" IN (.....)

CollectionMembership Load   SELECT "collection_memberships".* FROM 
"collection_memberships"  WHERE "collections"."kind" = 'brand' AND 
"collection_memberships"."collectable_type" = 'Product' AND 
"collection_memberships"."collectable_id" IN (...)  ORDER BY 
collection_memberships.position ASC

[ERROR] PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for
table "collections"
LINE 1: ...mberships".* FROM "collection_memberships"  WHERE "collectio...
```

ActiveRecord is putting the "collections"."kind" = 'brand' in the query, when it is just loading the collection memberships. It seems like it should either be in the subsequent query that would follow or that query should have an inner join. Any suggestions? I'd like to keep this as an association.

The other relevant models:

```
class CollectionMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collection, touch: true
  belongs_to :collectable, polymorphic: true
end
```

and

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collection_memberships
  has_many :products, source_type: 'Product', through: :collection_memberships, source: :collectable
end
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant associations from `CollectionMembership` and `Collection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
has_many :brands, -> { where(collections:{kind:'brand'}) },
  through: :collection_memberships, source: :collection
```